# subprocess calls next command in queue before first has fully executed

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to automatically invoke a command using a list of files as variables. I want the command to execute, wait until it's fully finished, then start the next one.

```
file1 = ['A_1.txt', 'B_1.txt', 'C_1.txt']
file2 = ['A_2.txt', 'B_2.txt', 'C_2.txt']
output = ['A.out', 'B.out', 'C.out']

for 1, 2, out, in zip(file1, file2, output):
    subprocess.call(['arbitrarycommand', '-o', output, 1, 2])
```

However, I think the command I'm executing invokes subsequent processes so call exits prematurely leading to file truncation.

If I change subprocess.call to:

```
subprocess.Popen(['arbitrarycommand', '-o', output, 1, 2]).wait()
```

Then the first operation (i.e. A) works as intended and waits until a complete file is formed, but the subsequent ones (i.e. B + C etc.) do not.

If I change subprocess.call to:

```
subprocess.check_call(['arbitrarycommand', '-o', output, 1, 2])
```

Then I get a non 0 exit -11.

Just to provide an alternative approach to the question, is there any other way to loop through a single instance of `Popen` for each member of the list, as that is managing to execute a single (multi component) process to completion.

Comment: This seems to be more of a problem with `command` than with `subprocess` or Python. After all, you state "the command I'm executing invokes subsequent processes", which implies the external command runs more processes, not `subprocess`.

Comment: It's also unclear what you are actually executing: `command -o A.out 1 2` doesn't really do anything (`-o` is even invalid for `command`). Please make a proper example that shows your problem.

Comment: Indeed, but I was just wondering if there is a python work around to wait for a command that spawns other processes?

For example, Popen with wait() lets the first one in the sequence finish, but not the rest. Maybe there's another way to queue the jobs up in a loop? Very new to python so not sure if I'm doing it in a logical way!

Comment: Sorry, I was using command as an example. The program I'm invoking is an uncommon scientific application and the inputs are much longer than that, just tried to boil it down to essentials for the example.

Comment: "if there is a python work around to wait for a command that spawns other processes? ". No, not unless the original command waits for its child processes to finish. If it spawns its children as individual processes, then those children are completely independent. That's nothing about Python, more how *nix works (if you're on Windows, I don't really know, but I expect something similar).

Comment: You could attempt something with keeping track of process IDs, or check for files that the children create (and remove upon finishing, like a PID file), but otherwise, I don't think there's a way around this.